# Do inserts block selects in firebird?

Tags: firebird

We are running some tests on firebird. When we insert, we notice that if we open a second sessions, that session hangs. So inserts appear to block selects.

is there an option of some sort to enable concurrency. Or do inserts,updates,deletes block an entire table?

do selects also block other sessions selecting?

Comment: That must be something else because in Firebird writers don't block readers because of its MVCC architecture (like most modern DBMS do), see here: http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/multi-version-concurrency-control/ (Btw: I personally would choose Postgres over Firebird unless the option to embedd the DBMS is a hard requirement).

Comment: A select doesn't block anything in Firebird. You shall include the minimum SQL you run in each sesion, including the one succeeding and the one that blocks to better explain your problem. You also have to mention the Firebird version you're testing.

Comment: With the 'wrong' transaction parameters it is possible that writers block readers, if the transaction is set up with `tpb_no_rec_version` and `tpb_wait`, so also include your connection library, transaction settings etc. See also http://firebird.1100200.n4.nabble.com/Writer-block-reader-issue-tp1106813p1106814.html

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: are those "transaction parameters" something that can be controlled through SQL? Or is this something that is completely controlled by the driver (e.g. JDBC, .Net)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Usually the driver has a sane default for the 'standard' isolation levels, but for example Jaybird allows a user to override this (eg by overriding the global config for the isolation level, or with a non-standard option to explicitly set specify it for a connection ([see setTransactionParameters](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/2.2.3/docs/org/firebirdsql/jdbc/FirebirdConnection.html#setTransactionParameters(int,%20org.firebirdsql.gds.TransactionParameterBuffer)) and the other method with that name.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There is also [`SET TRANSACTION`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-set-trans.html), but I am not sure if it can be used in all cases (I mostly deal with JDBC and there using commands like that directly are 'not allowed' by the spec, and as a driver implementer I don't deal with it as Firebird has an api for it)

Comment: yup. its set transaction. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no, inserts do not block writers in Firebird. However, in practice this depends on the configuration of the transactions involved.

For example, when you use a transaction with [`READ COMMITTED NO RECORD_VERSION`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref40/firebird-40-language-reference.html#fblangref40-transacs-settransac-readcommit), then if a record is read that has an uncommitted version from another transaction, then one of two things can happen:

1. If a `WAIT` transaction is configured, it will block until the pending transaction for the record is committed or rolled back.

   If the transaction has a `LOCK TIMEOUT` set, the select will end with an error if this doesn't happen before the timeout expires.
2. If a `NO WAIT` transaction is configured, it will immediately end the select with an error.

Note that since Firebird 4.0, the `[NO] RECORD_VERSION` option is ignored if the setting `ReadConsistency` is set to `1` (the default!) and instead it will apply `READ COMMITTED READ CONSISTENCY`.